# How can i replace complete html including tags and other stuf?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**I want to change or replace complete html tag not just inner it  :**

```
 function addToLikes(image_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/addToLikes.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                image_id: image_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById(image_id).innerHTML = `<i class="bi bi-heart-fill ms-3" onclick="removeFromLikes('<?php echo $row['image_id'] ?>')" style="cursor:pointer"></i>`;
            }
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <i class="bi bi-heart ms-3" id="<?php echo $row['image_id'] ?>" onclick="addToLikes('<?php echo $row['image_id'] ?>')" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
```

Comment: What about [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Comment: @james Thanks man , it worked :)

Comment: Or maybe better use `element.parentNode.replaceChild(new, old)`. But then you have to create the new child first with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way - much faster and does not make the DOM flicker

```js
$(".bi").on("click",  function(e) {
  const $this = $(this)
  const liked = $this.hasClass("bi-heart-fill");
  $.post("functions/toggleLikes.php', { id: $this.data("id"), liked:liked },function() {
    liked = !liked;
    $this.toggleClass("bi-heart-fill",liked)
    $this.toggleClass("bi-heart",!liked)
  })
})
```

```html
  <i class="bi bi-heart<?= $liked?"fill":"" ?> ms-3" data-id="<?php echo $row['image_id'] ?>" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
</div>
```